# How to get all the requests in view results tree in jmeter excluding same requests?

Tags: jmeter

I want to capture all the Requests in view resilts tree in seperate file excluding the same requests.

Can we use Bean shell sampler for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you can just write the viewresults to file, and read them into a collection of strings in beanshell... how many results are you talking about? you may want to write these to a db table and do a select unique if you have a lot of results.

[image: write view results to file]